# fetching all the data from the database based on user input matching only some part of a field in database using php

Tags: php, arrays, post, explode

I have IP address like below in my database.

10.00.54.58, 10.75.103.101, 10.50.44.11

I am taking user input for IP address. I want the user to fetch all the data even if the user enters any of the ip(in this case either he enters 10.00.54.58 or 10.75.103.101 or 10.50.44.11), he should get all the data based on that filter.

How can i modify my below code so that it fetches all data based on any of the IP address. Or can i make a separate function and call it here. Kindly help

Given :

const REGEXP_SECLOGS_IP = "/^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$/";

```
 $requestObj = new PagesviewlogEventRequest();
            $requestObj->userid = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_USERID, (($_POST['userid']) ?? FALSE) )) ? $_POST['userid']:FALSE;
            $requestObj->fromdate = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_DATE_ZULU, (($_POST['startdate']) ?? FALSE) )) ? $_POST['startdate']:NULL;
            $requestObj->todate = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_DATE_ZULU, (($_POST['enddate']) ?? FALSE) )) ? $_POST['enddate']:NULL;
            $requestObj->clientip = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_IP, (($_POST['clientip']) ?? FALSE) )) ? $_POST['clientip']:FALSE;
            $requestObj->limit = (Utils::validatePattern(Utils::REGEXP_SECLOGS_LIMIT, (($_POST['limit']) ?? FALSE) )) ? $_POST['limit']:'';
```

I tried to create a function and later on call it in the above code but not sure how to proceed:

```
public static function getIPRegexp()
    {
        $clientip = explode(", ",$clientip);
        foreach ($clientip as $key => $value) {

           preg_match("/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/",$clientip, $matches);
        }
    }
```

Kindly help. I am new to php so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using a very poor database design. Normalize your table structure with unique relation between data and cells (one ip in each cell in your case) and all your issue will fade away

Comment: as a side note: if you have an ip in the input and an ip in the db (after the explode) just do if input_ip==database_ip no? no need for regexp.